# CSS not overriding unless I use inspect tool

Tags: css

I'm getting a little confused by a CSS question I've got on a WP site I'm working on.

There's a theme installed which always includes a header class on each new page (.title-banner) and I want to hide this on this one specific page. I don't have access to the stylesheets so I just wanted to use CSS to hide the element on this one page, using display: none;, however it won't work if I put it within a  tag directly on my page. If I apply the CSS in the inspect tool, it does however work.
[image]
[image: inspect tool]

Is there a way I can get this to register by using on-page CSS rather than within the stylesheet, as this isn't an option? I know display: none; and !important isn't ideal but I don't know any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific to override existing CSS.

You can add this to your theme, or by going to "Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS" from your wp-admin.

Replace the Page ID with the page ID of your page... You can find it by looking at the admin page ID, or inspecting the `<body>` tag.  Wordpress puts the page-id-xxx class in the body of every page, allowing you to override specific CSS on a page by page basis.

```css
/* Replace Page ID with your page id */
.page-id-336 .title-banner {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it's much appreciated. I tried this on my page and tested it in a few places but it didn't seem to register at all for some reason.

Comment: This will definitely work. Add it to the WordPress customizer in Additional CSS. Also do you want display none or background color?

Comment: I wanted the banner to display none, but only on one specific page, not the whole theme

Answer (score 0):

You should try Javascript. I think your CSS styles are getting overridden by some default ones.
Use this;

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('.title-banner').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and suggestion. I tried this script at the top and bottom of my page but it doesn't seem to be registering for some reason! This is what I used (as it's not got an ID, only a class, and I can't add an ID to it)

<script>
    document.getElementByClassName("title-banner").style.display = "none";
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
    <script>

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('class_of_your_element').style.display = 'none !important';
}); 
    </script>
```